# How to force event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, django, fetch

Inside my fetch function, I'm sending a `mail` variable through a POST request to my server as JSON. In my server I open my database and check if the `mail` exists, and if it does, I add to my jsoned dict a string `{"exists":"exists"}` So I know that it exists. Then, still on the server side, I return a JSONResponse of my dict back to the js. I want my javascript to detect if it exists, so i look for the string i added to my dict. I look for `result.exists` in my script.

I only want the form to be prevented from submit if the email doesn't exists, and want the form to be submitted if the email already exists. So I`m doing:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector('#laform, #elform').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {


    var content = document.querySelector('#elcontent').value;

    fetch("", {

      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        mail: document.querySelector('#email').value,
        name: document.querySelector('#name').value
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // Print result
 
        if (result.exists === undefined) {

            event.preventDefault();

              if (content.length > 700) {
                  popup_content('show');

               }
        }
    });
  });
})

  </script>
```

But here is a big problem. Inside the `.then()` it's too late to add an `event.preventDefault()` So I don't know how to stop the form to be submitted under that condition. I can't put it out of the `.then()` beacuse I only want it under that condition. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using `event.preventDefault()` on the beginning of the event listener and submitting the form with `form.submit()` after you find `result.exists !== undefined`?

Comment: I didn't think about that. Thank you @RifatBinReza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `preventDefault()` regardless, if the event is trusted (initiated by user action). Inside the fetch, if the result doesn't exist, submit the form by calling `.submit()` on it (resulting in an *untrusted* event):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector('#laform, #elform').addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    if (!event.isTrusted) {
      // Submission was done via JS, not user; submit form
      return;
    }
    const content = document.querySelector('#elcontent').value;
    fetch("", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          mail: document.querySelector('#email').value,
          name: document.querySelector('#name').value
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        // Print result
        if (result.exists === undefined) {
          if (content.length > 700) {
            popup_content('show');
          }
        } else {
          // Submit form, resulting in untrusted event:
          this.submit();
        }
      });
  });
})
```

Comment: You are a life savior. I can accept your answer in 4 minutes. Thank you